How to properly join geometry in node editor?
I am trying to create plants in Blender using Geometry Nodes and have been following a tutorial video. I could have swore I followed everything correctly but to no luck. As you might see, I am trying to get that leaf (on the right) onto the stem (at the center). The reference video is https://youtu.be/b0-XCM1olp4?si=sZhT84_HGyDd-IUF&t=403
On the video the leaf appears when linking Instance on Points node to Join Geometry node, but on my end it's not happening so there must be some error.

Any help much appreciated!

The "join geometry" doesn't actually move the objects together, it simply joins the geometry data so you can plug everything to the output (or do something else with it with more nodes).
If you want the leaf to be on the stem, you're gonna have to do some math to either create the point on the stem or moving the leaf instance to a point on the stem after instantiating it.

@AlexandreMarcati that appears to be a complete answer, please post it as such.

Instance on Points connects the "origin" of the instance to a face of the main geometry.
So you need to move the leaf's origin to the base of its stem.
Using the 3D Cursor, you can:

Go to Edit Mode for the leaf
Select a vertex of face in the base of the stem of the leaf
Shift+S to snap Cursor to Selected (you will see the 3D cursor go to the base of the stem)
Go to Object Mode and select the leaf
Right click, Set Origin > Origin to 3D Cursor.


Yes. This works now. Apparently my Curve has fewer points than the one on the tutorial and I had to adjust some nodes also. Your answer helped me. Thanks so much!
